# blow a hole in vs open a hole in

Tags: idioms, grammaticality-in-context

What's the difference between:

1. The president's statements blown a hole in the country.
2. The president's statements opened a hole in the country.

Comment: _Blew_ or _have blown_.

Answer (score 1):

“Blow” suggests violence.  To blow a hole in a vessel, you need explosives, or at least a great deal of pressure.

“Open” suggests attention, care, and deliberation.  You can open a hole with a drill or a scalpel.

(And a statement cannot blow or open a hole in a country. It might blow a hole in someone’s credibility, or one side’s argument, but a “hole in a country” is not a thing.)

Comment: How about ''the president's statemnts blew a hole in the economy''?                                
                                                                                                                                         
I'm trying to understand the nuance difference in the expression ''blow a hole in'' when changing the verb ''blow'' to ''open''.

Comment: _Blow a hole in_ suggests violence, or, metaphorically, some sudden and drastic change.